# Getting peaks/troughs and charting

Tags: python, pandas

I am analysing swings in data which resembles a sine wave.

I have got a solution but am looking for something shorter.

Currently I find the peaks and trough building a df for each and merging with the main data. I then make a series with the diffs and draw a box plot.

Do I need to make those two dfs? Its a lot of code to do something simple...

The reason for doing this is I want to be able to compare the swings in temperature data over time. With this method I will be able to go on and compare say Dec 22 with Dec 21.

For this example I am using scipy data.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.datasets import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy import ndimage

temp = electrocardiogram()[200:300]
temp = ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(x, 2)
peaks, _= find_peaks(temp)
troughs, _= find_peaks(-temp)

troughs_df = pd.DataFrame()
troughs_df.index = troughs
troughs_df['troughs'] = 'trough'

peaks_df = pd.DataFrame()
peaks_df.index = peaks
peaks_df['peaks'] = 'peak'

temp = pd.Series(temp, name='temp')
temp = pd.merge(temp, troughs_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
temp = pd.merge(temp, peaks_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

temp['peaks and troughs'] = temp[['peaks', 'troughs']].fillna('').sum(axis=1)
temp.query("`peaks and troughs` != ''")['temp'].diff().plot.box()
```

input data from scipy

```
array([ 0.125,  0.16 ,  0.165,  0.17 ,  0.185,  0.22 ,  0.225,  0.235,
        0.22 ,  0.23 ,  0.25 ,  0.28 ,  0.27 ,  0.25 ,  0.255,  0.245,
        0.235,  0.235,  0.25 ,  0.23 ,  0.245,  0.23 ,  0.22 ,  0.215,
        0.18 ,  0.12 ,  0.075,  0.065,  0.06 ,  0.055,  0.025, -0.005,
       -0.04 , -0.085, -0.135, -0.145, -0.14 , -0.12 , -0.12 , -0.16 ,
       -0.195, -0.2  , -0.215, -0.2  , -0.2  , -0.215, -0.255, -0.27 ,
       -0.225, -0.225, -0.24 , -0.25 , -0.23 , -0.19 , -0.18 , -0.2  ,
       -0.21 , -0.215, -0.21 , -0.21 , -0.205, -0.225, -0.23 , -0.24 ,
       -0.245, -0.23 , -0.23 , -0.21 , -0.2  , -0.185, -0.175, -0.175,
       -0.19 , -0.19 , -0.19 , -0.2  , -0.175, -0.13 , -0.09 , -0.095,
       -0.13 , -0.17 , -0.16 , -0.135, -0.1  , -0.09 , -0.115, -0.115,
       -0.08 , -0.04 , -0.065, -0.105, -0.12 , -0.12 , -0.11 , -0.105,
       -0.11 , -0.15 , -0.155, -0.16 ])
```

output

```
temp        troughs peaks   peaks and troughs
13  0.3     NaN     peak    peak
48  -0.2    trough  NaN     trough
56  -0.2    NaN     peak    peak
63  -0.2    trough  NaN     trough
89  -0.1    NaN     peak    peak
```

[image]

Comment: It might help everyone, if you added some sample data, and an explanation of what and why you are doing this.

Comment: I have add samples of the data. The script is self contained so if run the data will pull from ```scipy.datasets```